# How can I find the value from json ds_map?

Tags: json, steam-web-api, game-maker, gml

I am trying to get SteamAPI's SteamID value from this JSON link:

```
steam_request = http_get("http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetPlayerSummaries/v0002/?key=A689432685442875EBB8B6E4039D73AE&steamids=76561198074393173");
result_map = json_decode(steam_request);
steam_id = ds_map_find_value(result_map, "steamid");
```

When I am trying to get the string from this variable, it just tell me that this variable in undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`http_get` returns an identifier, not a data. You should use this identifier in [HTTP Event](http://docs.yoyogames.com/source/dadiospice/001_advanced%20use/more%20about%20async%20events/http.html) to get the data. Read the [documentation](http://docs.yoyogames.com/source/dadiospice/002_reference/asynchronous%20functions/http_get.html) for details